# How to use a PKCS8 Encoded Private Key in PHP

Tags: java, php, openssl, rsa, private-key

The following code in java does the job:

```
        InputStream is = CipherRunnable.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("privateKey.pem");
        byte[] bytes = new byte[is.available()];
        is.read(bytes);
        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec privateKeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(bytes);
        KeyFactory keyFactory;
        keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        Key key = keyFactory.generatePrivate(privateKeySpec);
```

What is the equivalent code in PHP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how you can create PKCS8 public / private keys in PHP using [phpseclib, a pure PHP RSA implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/rsa/intro.html):

```
<?php
include('Crypt/RSA.php');

$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();

$rsa->setPrivateKeyFormat(CRYPT_RSA_PRIVATE_FORMAT_PKCS8);
$rsa->setPublicKeyFormat(CRYPT_RSA_PUBLIC_FORMAT_PKCS8);

extract($rsa->createKey());

echo $privatekey . "\r\n\r\n";
echo $publickey;
```

Comment: Clearly this doesn't align with what was asked. The original question was about loading an already created PKCS8 key, while this answer just generate a new one

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use OpenSSL only, there don't appear to be any PKCS8 functions for PHP that I can find; whatever version of OpenSSL you have is the default format you get.

Here's what I ended up doing, courtesy of [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/606215/openssl-pkcs8-default-format-gives-rsa-private-key) and the [OpenSSL RSA Tool documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/rsa.html). Note I am creating entirely new self-signed certs/keys, so if you aren't you can skip all but the last few lines:

```
<?php
// Create the private and public key
$sslConfig = array(
    "digest_alg" => "sha512",
    "private_key_bits" => 4096,
    "private_key_type" => OPENSSL_KEYTYPE_RSA,
);

$privKey = openssl_pkey_new($sslConfig);

$csrConfig = array(
    "countryName" => "yourcountry",
    "stateOrProvinceName" => "yourstate",
    "localityName" => "yourcity",
    "organizationName" => "yourcompany",
    "organizationalUnitName" => "yourorg",
    "commonName" => "your.domain.name"
);

// create a certificate signing request
$csr = openssl_csr_new($csrConfig, $privKey, $sslConfig);
// self-sign for 365 days
$signed = openssl_csr_sign($csr, null, $privKey, 365, $sslConfig);

// Extract the public certificate
openssl_x509_export($signed, $sslCert);

// Extract the private key (in default openssl format, which for 1.x will be PKCS8 / "PRIVATE KEY" format)
openssl_pkey_export($privKey, $sslKey);

// Convert private key to RSA ("traditional" / "SSLeay" / "RSA PRIVATE KEY") format
exec('echo '.escapeshellarg($sslKey).' | openssl rsa -outform PEM 2>/dev/null', $output, $return_var);

$traditionalSslKey = implode("\n", $output);

var_dump($traditionalSslKey); // private key
var_dump($sslcert); // certificate (public key is available via openssl_pkey_get_public($sslcert))
```